# Selecting date for torque animation load using Torque?

Tags: carto, torque

I have an animation working using Torque, and the animation is set to pause on load. this automatically loads on the first date of the data series. Is there a way to draw the animation so that it loads on a specified date? My viz also has a datepicker that I would like to be able to set to control the animation so that if I select a date from the datepicker, the animation jumps/redraws and loads to that same date while still having the full timeline of data.

Here's my current code.

Is there a way to set the step in the .on('load') method?

```
// Draw animation layer using torque
cartodb.createLayer(map, reservoir_storage_layer, options = {https:true, time_slider:true})
  .addTo(map, 1)
  .done(function(layer) {
      layer.on('change:time', function(changes){
          var currentDate = layer.getTime();
          //console.log(currentDate);
          if (changes.step === layer.provider.getSteps() - 1) {
                  layer.pause();
          };
      });
      layer.on('load', function(){
          layer.pause();
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setStep() method handles this. Easy fix!

```
// calculate start step
step = Math.round((new Date(selectDate) - new Date(startDate))/(1000*60*60*24))
console.log(step)

// Draw animation layer using torque
cartodb.createLayer(map, reservoir_storage_layer, options = {https:true, time_slider:true})
  .addTo(map, 1)
  .done(function(layer) {
      layer.on('change:time', function(changes){
          var currentDate = layer.getTime();
          //console.log(currentDate);
          if (changes.step === layer.provider.getSteps() - 1) {
                  layer.pause();
          };
      });
      layer.on('load', function(){
          layer.setStep(step);
          layer.pause();
      });
  })
```

Comment: mark the question as answered then, please :)